# Screen Dump to pdf? (Ubuntu 23.04)

Tags: clipboard, capture

The Print Screen button works very well for capture to the clipboard, but I want it to create a pdf file of the image. It has the various selection sources, but output only goes to the clipboard.

What's the easiest way? Is there a similar tool with the pdf option?

I added the Ubuntu version. I'm aware of the Costales "Clipboard to File" program on Github, but the author tells me that it doesn't run past 22.04 because of a GTK4 issue that he couldn't resolve in later releases. In addition, it doesn't convert to pdf, it goes to text or png.

As far as pasting into Libreoffice writer, that ends up with a PDF of a page with a image inside. I want a pdf of the image itself.

Comment: Which release of Ubuntu? It matters.

Comment: Paste to LO Writer, save as PDF.

Comment: You can use `gimp` 'File -- Create -- From clipboard or Screenshot ...', so either via the clipboard or directly. When the image is in gimp, you can export it as pdf.

Comment: I think you can get more control of the image quality (of the pdf file), if you first make an image file (png or jpg format depending on type of image) and then use ImageMagick `convert` with 'some options' to convert it to a pdf file.